# Getting factors of Mersenne numbers. Why does $2^p-1|2^b-1$ where $p|b$ and $p$ is prime and $b\in Z$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, mersenne-numbers

Why does $2^p-1|2^b-1$ where $p|b$ and $p$ is prime and $b\in Z$?

I'm working with Mersenne numbers and factorization of numbers to a large power minus 1 and the solution to the problems are to find a prime that divides $b$ then $2^p-1$ will divide $2^b-1$

Comment: If $b=pc$ then $2^b-1=(2^p)^c-1=(2^p-1+1)^c-1=\sum_{n=\mathbf{1}}^{c}\binom{c}{n}(2^p-1)^n$

Comment: that's kind of cool actually

Comment: @user8714896 The first coimment boils down to $\, a\mid (a\!+\!1)^n-1,\,$ which can be proved in many ways besides the Binomial Theorem, e.g. Factor Theorem, Taylor's Theorem, modular arithmetic (congruences), induction, etc.